# Map screen coordinates to an image with different height / width ratio

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, math

Imagine there's an image of a car on the screen and the user pressed the door. I want to know that the user has pressed the door. The problem lies in that all mobile screen sizes are different. I also need the ratio of the image to remain constant as it will look odd.

I've tried to come up with a solution for this problem and have currently got to this point.

Here's what I'm doing so far

Get the position of the touch event.
Divide the x and y position of the touch event by the screen width and height respectively.
This now gives me an x and y position between 0 and 1. Top left is 0,0. Bottom right is 1,1

I know the screen ratio is 2960 : 1440 = 1 : 0.48648648648649;

I know the image ratio is 2960 : 1000 = 1 : 0.33783783783784;

I have an object which I plotted the different car part positions relative to the image itself on 0 - 1. I did this in photoshop

```
carParts: {
  door: {
    xMin: 0.3,
    xMax: 0.4,
    yMin: 0.6,
    yMax: 0.72
  },
  hood: {
    xMin: etc,
  }
}
```

I know that this could potentially work if I could now map the screen positions to the positions I've already worked out. I think I need some kind offset that I could use by using the ratios somehow. Am I doing this completely wrong or is it possible with the information I have?

Here's how the image looks overlayed on the screen.

[image]